# SQL Partially search users

Tags: sql-server, razor-2, asp.net-webpages

I need to try and partially search for users, right now, my code is only finding results based on the EXACT username. How can I do this?

My code can be found below, please notice that I'm using "@0", which somehow seems to prevent me from using %@0%.

```
Here's my code:
@{
    Layout = "~/Admin/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

    var db = Database.Open("MikZeRCoding2");
    var userSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE UserName = @0";

    var UsernameSearch = "";
    var ErrorMessage = "";
    var searchString = Request.Form["search-username"];

    if (IsPost) {
        UsernameSearch = Request.Form["search-username"];

        if (UsernameSearch.IsEmpty()) {
            ErrorMessage = "You didn't search for anything.";
        }

        if (!UsernameSearch.IsEmpty() && db.QueryValue(userSearchQuery, UsernameSearch) == null) {
            ErrorMessage = "No results for '" + searchString + "' were found...";
        }

        if (searchString == "bitch") {
            ErrorMessage = "Bitch spotted in-front of your pc monitor.";
        }

        else {

        }
    }
}

<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="search-username" placeholder="Search for a user" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="button"></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />

    @foreach(var user in db.Query(userSearchQuery, UsernameSearch)) {
        <a href="@Href("~/Admin/Accounts/User", user.UserId)"><span>[ @user.UserId ]</span>  @user.UserName</a>
    }
    @if(!ErrorMessage.IsEmpty()) {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">@ErrorMessage</div>
    }
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to do:

```
var userSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE UserName LIKE '%' + @0 + '%'";
```

EDIT:

To return nothing when `@0` is empty:

```
var userSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE UserName LIKE '%' + @0 + '%' and @0 <> ''";
```

Comment: That actually works, thank you!! However, unfortunately, when i do that and I go to the page the search-box is on, it seems that it outputs EVERY user, then when I search for like "use" it comes up with only "User", if you get what i mean :P Any way to fix this?

Comment: @user3250722 . . . Are you saying that when the search string is empty, it is returning all users.  What should it be returning?

Comment: Yeah I know, it's me being silly. But I've been trying to fix that issue so it doesn't automatically search for nothing when the page is loaded, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually do that.